# Search for “whole word match” and highlight that word in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I need to help find out  match word in PHP preg_replace_callback function. How can be find out the  exact word 'Invitation.'  from a sentence? I need to highlight that word.
I need solution from using this function **'preg_replace_callback'**

```
$search_word = 'Invitation.'
$string = '/\b' . preg_quote($search_word) . '\b/i'; 
preg_replace_callback($string, 
                function($matches) use (&$counter) {
                   
                   $counter++;
                   return '<b class="search_mark highlighted" id="matched_'. $counter . '">'
                       . substr($matches[0], 0, strlen($matches[0]))
                    
                       . '</b>' ;
            }, $text);
```

Comment: You're looking for a word within word boundaries, but your `$search_word` has a period on the end. I.e. it is never can be within word boundaries (except when new word started right after the period). If you want to match any string including a period, then you should not limit the search by `\b`

Comment: @AterLux yes.  I'm working with searching words , that time four category used match case,Match entire word only,Wrap around,Regular expression. so its progressing dynamically search. user can select normal search or any above mentioned search categories . So I'm facing difficult when search entire word search.

Comment: Maybe try and match a word boundary _or_ a white space character before/after? If that doesn’t do it for you, then you need to be more specific with your actual requirement.

Comment: I think there's a bit of confusion about what you mean by a 'word'. 'Invitation' is a word, 'Invitation.' is a word plus a punctuation character. Also what is meant by a sentence (in English at least). If it is a sentence with normal format can you assume that the . ends the sentence, in which case using a $ in the regex may be helpful etc.